# Ranking in R based on multiple criteria

Tags: r

I am working in R would like some help on ranking with multiple criteria. Using the `mtcars` dataset - I want to generate a new column in this case based initially on the rank of `mtcars$mpg`, then in the case of ties for this to be decided by the rank of mtcars$qsec for example. I have `mtcars["rank"] = NA` then `mtcars$rank=rank(mtcars$mpg)` but not sure how to include how to deal with the ties. I've tried `mtcars$rank=order(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$qsec)` but not getting the outcome I want - I want the initial ranking for `mtcars$mpg` and in the event of ties for this to be decided by the lower ranking in `mtcars$qsec`. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a [minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) question, including sample data and code attempted. If you don't want to use your own data, consider a similar problem with a pre-installed dataset such as `mtcars` or `iris` (to name but two).

Comment: Thanks - sorry I'm new to R and SO. Easier to use the mtcars dataset - I want to generate a new dataset or say column in this case based initially on the rank of `mtcars$mpg`, then in the case of ties for this to be decided by the rank of `mtcars$qsec` for example. I have `mtcars[rank] = NA` then `mtcars$rank=rank(mtcars$mpg)` but not sure how to include how to deal with the ties.

Comment: Additionally, `order(...)` allows multiple levels, so `order(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$qsec)` does what you (I?) think it should.

Comment: I don't see in the help how to break the ties based on the value of another column?

Comment: @Emily please edit your question and add details provided in the comments. Thanks

Comment: Thanks updated the question now.

Comment: Does `mtcars$mpgrnk[order(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$qsec)] <- 1:nrow(mtcars)` work?

Comment: Yes, that seems to have done it! Just getting my head around differences between rank and order... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would first `order` it based on `mpg` and `qsec`.

> mtcars <- mtcars[order(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$qsec), ]

Ranking is now simply giving indexing to the dataframe.

> mtcars$rank <- 1:nrow(mtcars)